# bash: check if the found file exists

Tags: bash, find

The following function checks if the file test.exe exist somewhere on the usb key and run this file, or terminate the flow.

```
quick_amber(){
local crazy_path=$(find /media/user/KINGSTON -type f -name test.exe)
if [ -f $crazy_path ]; then
echo "We are going to prepare jobs for AMBER!"
elif [ ! -f $crazy_path ]; then
echo "Good bye !"
fi
}
```

the issue that elif does not work, so if the file is not found it continue to trying execution

```
find: ‘/media/user/KINGSTON’: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

edited:
does the problem related enterily to double quoting of the "$crazy_path", which apparently could resolve the issue ?

Comment: `elif [ ! -f $crazy_path ]` could be just an `else`

Comment: I've tried the both and it did not work I've just was able to fix the issue putting "$crazy_path" in double qouites ! ;-)

Comment: `find` can easily return multiple files; running it in a command substitution is not robust because the shell will split the result on whitespace. Why would you expect `find` to return a file which doesn't exist, anyway?

Comment: here the aim was to find a file test.sh on the usb media. if you know better way, please share it here !!

Comment: "it doesn't work" requires you to tell us what "would work". Maybe you need `else echo "Good bye!" ; exit 1 ; fi`. Good luck.

Comment: or `return 1` if you just want to leave the function with a return code that signals problems.

Answer (score 0):

Double quoting makes the difference:

```
$ [ -f ]; echo $?
0
$ [ -f "" ]; echo $?
1
```

To avoid the problem if the find command returns more than one file put the results in an array, e.g.:

```
locale all_files=($(find /media/user/KINGSTON -type f -name test.exe))
```

then you can simply test:

```
if ((${#all_files[*]} > 0)); then
    echo "found at least one file"
else
    echo "found nothing"
fi
```